# Adding Styles in ADXStudio contact form

Tags: crm, adxstudio-portals

I am us ADXStudio CRM. I want to add CSS styles in my existing contact form. So I please help me in adding the css styles in label and text box.ere
Here goes my code

```
<asp:Content ID="Content6" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentBottom" runat="server">
<%: Html.HtmlAttribute("adx_copy") %>
    <crm:CrmDataSource ID="WebFormDataSource" runat="server" />
        <adx:CrmEntityFormView ID="ProfileFormView" runat="server"
        DataSourceID="WebFormDataSource"
        CssClass="crmEntityFormView"
        EntityName="contact"
        FormName="ContactPref"
        ValidationGroup="Profile"
        ValidationSummaryCssClass="alert alert-danger alert-block"
        RecommendedFieldsRequired="True"
        ShowUnsupportedFields="False"
        ToolTipEnabled="true"
        ClientIDMode="Static"

         />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using CRMEntityFormView (which is the default out of the box contact us form view), you should look for `.crmEntityForm` class.

```
.crmEntityFormView .cell input[type=text], .crmEntityFormView .cell select, .crmEntityFormView .cell textarea {
background-color:blue;
}
.crmEntityFormView .cell label{
background-color:red;
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your help its appreciated, and also can i add the placeholder inside the text box only using CSS ?

Comment: @nwemember,No, placeholder is an html attribute, cannot be achieved using just CSS, try to use javascript to dynamically add placeholders.